# Option "start Server" in BOBI4.2 is not displayed

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I use BOBI4.2. When I access the CMC with Administrator, then go to "Servers", and right-clic on a server, I find the options "Start Server, Stop Server...".
Now, when I access the CMC with another user that belongs to the group Administrators, and right-clic on a server, I don't find these options.

Administrator:
[Options displayed for Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4pP.png)

Another user:
[Options not displayed for other users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYe3.png)

Do you have any idea how I can let them appear?
Thanks in advance for your response.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Check top-level security settings for Servers.  The Administrator user automatically has Full Control over everything, but that is not necessarily true for the Administrators group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your return. But I am a beginner in BOBI4.2 and I don't know how to grant top-level rights for the Administrators group on all servers. Can you please give me more details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Servers area in CMC, go to the "Manage" button, then "Top level security" -> All Users.  If "Administrators" is in the list, then click it at "Assign Security", then select Full Control.  If Administrators is not in the list, then you'll first need to add it via Add Principals.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I did what you proposed, but the problem is still there.